android Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest fails with error : caused by: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: malformed sequence in RSA private key
i'm trying to run basic instrumented test on my android app , to test room database , when i lunch the test , the task
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest 

always fails and throws the following error
caused by: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: malformed sequence in RSA private key

also worth nothing that it's my first time working with test , and i noticed that android studio shows 0 test , i don't know if that's related or another issue i need to solve separately.


here is my simple test class :
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.SmallTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class RequestsDaoTest {

    private lateinit var dataBase: RequestsDataBase
    private lateinit var requestDao: RequestDao


    @Before
    fun createDb(){
        dataBase = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            RequestsDataBase::class.java,
        ).allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()

        requestDao = dataBase.RequestDao()
    }


    @After
    fun closeDb(){
        dataBase.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun assert_one_record_added_after_insert(){
        runBlockingTest {
            requestDao.insert(Request("jj","ll","2024-12-23"))

            val data = requestDao.read()
            assert(data.size == 1)
        }
    }

} 



also here is my full logs of  the Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest task :
https://www.mashupstack.com/share/675c5c544d920
i tried changing  both gradle and my jdk but the issue persisted ,  i have searched online but zero results found.
